# MySql query for from date or to date exist select data

Tags: mysql, date, select, between

I have a table called `cubbersclosure`, data's added below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|
|      closureId      |     cubbersId    |  fromDate   |  toDate     |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|
|          3          |         3        |  2019-07-24 | 2019-07-25  |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|-------------|
```

I need to get data by following scenario:

1. If only `fromDate` or `toDate` exist in my query get the data.

**Eg:** `SELECT * FROM cubbersclosure cc WHERE CAST('2019-07-23' as date) <= cc.toDate AND CAST('2019-07-26' as date) >= cc.fromDate AND cc.cubbersId = '3'`

The above query `fromDate` and `toDate` not same in table. So i don't want to get the data. But this query fetch the data like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM cubbersclosure cc WHERE (cc.toDate=CAST('2019-07-23' as date)
OR cc.toDate=CAST('2019-07-26' as date) OR cc.fromDate=CAST('2019-07-23' as date)
OR cc.fromDate=CAST('2019-07-26' as date)) AND cc.cubbersId = '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it working, but if i select `2019-07-25` to `2019-07-26` get the data's

Comment: @RameshS check out the changed query

Comment: Sorry bro `'2019-07-23` to `'2019-07-26` data showing. I don't want to show the data

Comment: you want to get only the rows that match your input ..? @RameshS not if it is between ..?

Comment: both dates should match or any one is enough ..? @RameshS

Comment: All the dates match but if choose `2019-07-23` as `fromDate` and `2019-07-26` as `toDate` this date i don't want to get the rows. Expect this all dates are working  fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196848/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-andrews-b-anthony).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to return records for a given `cubbersId` which don't overlap with the from/to date range.  You may try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cubbersclosure
WHERE
    (toDate <= '2019-07-23' OR fromDate >= '2019-07-26') AND
    cubbersId = 3;
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Please clarify.

Comment: Actually if i select `2019-07-23` to `2019-07-24` i need to show that data because `2019-07-24` is exist in  `closure fromDate`

Comment: I edited the answer to make it closed on the `fromDate`.  Just change the inequalities as you require.

Comment: Sorry bro need to check `toDate` also for example if i select `2019-07-25` to `2019-07-28` i need to show that data because `2019-07-25` is exist in `closure  toDate`

Comment: Your comments are inconsistent with what my original answer was, which was closed on both ends.